# Quick question about equality of random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I have two RV $X$ and $Y$, and I am asked to find the probability of $P(X=Y)$. To tackle to problem, I've conditioned on $X$ and used the law of total probability to write :

$ 
P(X = Y) = \displaystyle \sum_{x \in S_X} P(Y = X | X = x) P(X = x) 
$

But now I'm wondering if I can write that $P(Y = X | X = x) = P(Y = x | X = x) = P(Y = x)$ without any information about dependence/independence between $X$ and $Y$, can someone tell me if the above equality holds, and if yes why ?

Here the whole problem :

Let $X$ be a r.v such that $G_X(z) = \dfrac{1}{(2-z)^5}$. Let $Y$ be a geometric r.v of parameter $p$. Find $P(X = Y)$. Hint : Do not try to compute $P(X=n)$.

Thanks !

Comment: Let $X$ be the number rolled on a fair $6$-sided die and let $Y$ be the number rolled at the same time on the same die; that is, $Y=X$ by definition. Then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. See which of your formulas works then.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $P(Y=X \mid X=x)$ as $P(Y=x \mid X=x)$ but then you cannot simplify further without resolving the dependence structure of $X$ and $Y$.

This way of proceeding to begin with it is also assuming $X$ and $Y$ are discrete, which maybe they are.

Comment: Yes they are, $Y$ follows a geometric distribution and we are given the generating function $G_X(z)$. How can I solve the problem then?

Comment: @Bozu At the end of the day you need to be given information about their joint distribution in some fashion, but what you just said only gives us the marginal distributions.

Comment: But in my problem, which is an exam problem, I have nothing else

Comment: @Bozu You can try stating the whole problem but what you just said at least makes it impossible to solve the problem.

Comment: I’ve added the whole problem

Comment: @Bozu Yeah no that's not technically possible. Without context and without an option to ask for clarification I would assume they are independent.

Comment: Okey, thank you !